# ROW_NUMBER Oracle - weird behavior (adds rows)

Tags: sql, oracle, row-number

The nested query between `--- 1 ---` and `--- 2 ---` returns a single row.
But the full query returns multiple rows.
How is this possible?

This doesn't make any sense to me, I guess I am missing something very subtle here.

```
 select                                                                                                             

 distinct                                                                                                           


 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY xx."accountCreateDate" DESC) as "rowNumber",
 xx.* 


 from 
 (
     --- 1 ---
         select 
         some stuff 
         from                                                                                                               
       t1                                     
       left join t2  on t1.id = t2.id 


         --- 2 ---
 ) xx  ;
```

**Oracle version info:**

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
"CORE   11.2.0.2.0  Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

FULL QUERY:

```
     select                                                                                                             

     distinct 

     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY xx."accountCreateDate" DESC) as "rowNumber",
     xx.* 

     from 
     (

             select 
             replace(t.company_name,'"', '###') as "companyName",                                                               
             t.main_email_address as "mainEmailAddress",                                                                        
             t.main_telephone_number as "mainPhoneNumber",                                                                      
             t.xref_id as "businessID",                                                                                    
             COALESCE(t.business_record_id, TO_NUMBER(a.ACCOUNT_ID__C)) as "integrationID",                                                                           

             a.id as "sAccountID",                                                                                           


             t.d_account_id as "dddAccountID",                                                                              
             t.region_name as "regionName",                                                                                     
             t.customer_key as "customerKey",                                                                                   
             t.region_key as "regionKey",                                                                                       
             t.ACCOUNT_CREATE_DT as "accountCreateDate",                                                                        
             t.ACCOUNT_LAST_UPDATE_DT as "accountLastUpdateDate",                                                               
             t.INSERT_DATE as "insertDate",                                                                                     
             t.LAST_REFRESH_DATE as "lastRefreshDate"                                                                           

             from                                                                                                               
             CRM_01.STDD_ACCOUNT t                                                                                            
             left join SF.Acct_Ids_Account a on t.xref_id = a.business_id_hidden__c                                
             where                                                                                                              
             (                                                                                                                  
             (1=1)                                                                                           
             )                                                                                                                  

             and                                                                                                                
             (                                                                                                                  
             ((t.business_record_id = '14413973') or (a.ACCOUNT_ID__C = '14413973'))                                                                                       
             )   


     ) xx  ;
```

Comment: The nested query *does not* return a single row or you just bump into some crazy bug. Please supply a reproducible scenario and your Oracle version.

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz Yes, the query inside `xx` returns a single row. I can see it with my eyes.

Comment: Great - so Please supply a reproducible scenario and your Oracle version

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz I already supplied the version. I will see if I can supply a reproducible example, this is not so easy as you know :)

Comment: If you replace your inner query with `select ... from dual`, do you get the same results?

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz I don't get the same results.

Comment: Simplify the query an much as you can until you get the minimal query that still has this issue.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible with a `select`.  But, you are using `select distinct`.  The subquery is not really returning one row.  It is returning multiple rows, all with the same values.

When you add the `row_number()` that adds a unique column.  Voila!  More rows appear.  The `row_number()` is evaluated before the `select distinct`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5cbec1063308da6fb26e077e14f5f5fa) is a simple db<>fiddle illustrating this phenomenon.

If you use `dense_rank()` instead, then you will probably do what you want.  You can also use a subquery and then `row_number()` in the outer query.  That said, I usually think that `select distinct` is used to mask other problems in queries/data.

Comment: I didn't get it. Select distinct from 1 row should still be 1 row with a unique number 1 added by row_number(). No?

Comment: @peter.petrov . . . No, the `row_number()` is evaluated BEFORE the `select distinct`.

Comment: Oh... OK thanks... I will try it without the `distinct`, it is redundant anyway, right? Since row_number adds a unique number.

Comment: This is weird... I wonder if it behaves the same way in SQL Server. I am really surprised by this behavior.

Comment: Seems removing the distinct didn't help either. I am trying further. This looks really crazy to me.

Comment: The subquery inside xx  is indeed returning 1 row.

Comment: Wait a min... In your dbfiddle example you have 2 rows in the table `t` with same value for the `x` column. This is not the same situation as in my scenario. My query inside `xx` really returns a single row when I execute it by itself.

Comment: @peter.petrov . . . That is actually not the question you have asked here.  There is clearly a `select distinct` in the code in the question.

Comment: Yes, there is distinct but the query in `xx` returns a single row when I run it by itself.

Comment: @peter.petrov can you perhaps reproduce this by replacing "some stuff" with some actual columns/data .. along with a structure/data of tables t1 and t2 .. to illustrate this behavior ..

Comment: @vishnud I posted the full query only with a few column names changed.

Comment: im afraid, it doesn't help to reproduce the issue you're facing. please also share data in both tables and illustrate the single row returned by your inner query. it's best to share a demo at https://dbfiddle.uk/ - i'm also upvoting @GordonLinoff's answer above as it makes perfect sense for the specific scenario